# How do I update to Giraffe?

Tags: starbound

How do I update my game to Upbeat Giraffe? I saw it recently came out, so I want to download it so me and my friend can continue playing. But, the game says it is up to date, despite while in game saying I am at Enraged Koala. Is there anyway to update the game files without deleted my local content?

Comment: Its not out yet, they are doing some last minute trouble shooting. Seems that they ran into some issues that could only be found while uploading the update to steam. If we are lucky we might get the update tonight, but it is looking like it will come out tomorrow. D:   https://www.reddit.com/r/starbound/comments/2tzd57/hark_a_stable_update_v_upbeat_giraffe/co3oobj

Comment: Ahh, I was checking the patch stuff, and it said it was out, so I assumed.

Comment: They did release the patch notes but said it wouldn't be released until later today, I quote: "At long last, we’re updating Starbound’s stable branch __later today__", emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update is now available and will download when you log into Steam, assuming you have automatic downloads on and are opted into Starbound's "stable branch".